# Calculating Fiscal Quarters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I need help with this code. Right now this is looking at calendar year quarters, but I would like to modify it to look at fiscal year quarters.

```
    Function test(time)
        Quarter = Format(time, "YYYYq")

        For vRow = 2 To 1000               
            report_time = Format(Sheets("data").Range("A" & vRow).Value, "YYYYq")

            Assessment = Sheets("data").Range("V" & vRow).Value  

            If (report_time = Quarter) Then
                denominator = denominator + 1
                If (Assessment= 1) Then
                    numerator = numerator + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next

        If denominator > 0 Then
            test = numerator / denominator
        Else
            test = 0
        End If            
    End Function
```

I would appreciate your time and suggestions regarding the same.

Comment: Which fiscal year quarters do you follow? You can put the fiscal quarters in a spreadsheet and then use a simple `Lookup` or `Index()Match()` formula to determine the fiscal year quarter a date falls in...

Comment: Seeing an example would be useful.

Comment: Also Avoid using `time` as a variable. It is a reserved word in VBA ;)

Comment: In terms of financial reporting you will have fiscal, calendar & actual. So are you working with any data vendor to get fiscal data? Or you are trying to simply code a fiscal quarters?

Comment: The quarters I am looking at are Feb, March, April as Q1, May, jun. july as Q2 and so on. Basically, I have first date of the quarter month (eg: 2/1/2012 for Q1) in my excel spreadsheet and the code identifies quarter from this date.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have more data to type and there's no enough space in the comments.

In terms of financial reporting you will have fiscal, calendar & actual. So please verify,

- if you are working with any data vendor to get fiscal year data.
- if you are planning to do any calendarization to the data? e.g. Turn fiscal year data into a calendar year data...etc
- **if you are going to compare fiscal year data of one company to another**
- Or you are trying to simply code a fiscal quarters from any fiscal year entered by a user without any **calendarizing**?

So if you want your code to be generic to all fiscal year/semi-annuals/quarters that a user chooses, then you need a pretty robus logic. ;) Because `Apple US` fiscal year that ends in September is not as same as `BHP AU` in June..

It's inevitable for fiscal year to have a life span from one calendar year to another if fiscal year Q4 doesn't tally with Calendar year Q4 which is `December`. **Most painful level is when your fiscal quarters do not fall into a Calendar quarter. Where Fiscal year ends in odd months..**. E.g. `WallMart US with January 31`. Usually some European or British stocks seems to have this nature. So you have to validate each month in that case.

I did a calendarized tool sometime back. So if you can clarify your requirements clearly, happy to help.

Comment: Thanks! I have trying to group several people into quarter group based on their birth date. To identify the quarters from the code above, I have the first date of the quarter month (eg: 2/1/2012 for Q1) in my excel spreadsheet and the code identifies quarter from this date.

Comment: @Nupur wow interesting, how does these birthday grouping connects to *fiscal* quarters? Anyway looking at your above comment, it's a classic ODD ending month fiscal year (e.g. January 31st) ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is how I am supposed to group people. I need help with modifying the code above to look at fiscal quarters.